# Missing methods in PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have a very generic database insert/query which works fine as a non-PCL method. I'm trying to move it over to a PCL project and for the majority of the code, there isn't a problem.

However, I'm finding that various System.Type methods are missing and I'm at a loss of how to fix the issues.

The three methods I'm having an issue with are `GetMethod`, `GetProperties` and `GetCustomAttributes`. `IgnoreAttribute` is missing as is the `Length` property.

I know that there have been changes to Reflection with the 78 profile, but I've not found anything that replaces the code

Comment: Platform dependent things should be handled by dependency injection, as shown in Xamarin article, http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

Comment: Given this though is more a reflection issue more than a say a xam forms issue, is there a way of implementing the missing methods as part of a PCL (such as can be done with the filer)?

Comment: You won't be able to add anything to pre-defined PCL profiles. So the workaround is exactly the same. That Xamarin article does not only apply to Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You can create an interface which will be provide `GetMethodInfo` method. After that you should implemented it for each platform specific project.

Answer (score 3):

Use extension methods, [this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1eeea41e110934e52bf7e6682d8751b885206844/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/ReflectionExtensions.cs) is how MvvmCross handled it.

[GetMethod](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1eeea41e110934e52bf7e6682d8751b885206844/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/ReflectionExtensions.cs#L136)

[GetProperties](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1eeea41e110934e52bf7e6682d8751b885206844/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/ReflectionExtensions.cs#L85)

[GetCustomAttributes](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1eeea41e110934e52bf7e6682d8751b885206844/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/ReflectionExtensions.cs#L30)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface `IReflectionHelper` into your PCL project.

```
/// <summary>
/// This interface provides some reflection methods which are not supported into PCL.
/// </summary>
    public interface IReflectionHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get <see cref="MethodInfo"/> for the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
        /// <param name="methodName">The name of the method.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns method info.</returns>
        MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Type type, string methodName);
    }
```

Then you should to implement it for each specific platform. This is an example for Android.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DroidReflectionHelper))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of the <see cref="IReflectionHelper"/> for Android platform.
    /// </summary>
    public class DroidReflectionHelper : IReflectionHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get <see cref="MethodInfo"/> for the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
        /// <param name="methodName">The name of the method.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns method info.</returns>
        public MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Type type, string methodName)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
            return methodInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

I used service locator in my sample. You can read more about it here: [Introduction to DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Reflection as using System.Reflection; in your class file.

And then install the TypeExtensions using the following command through the following command:

```
PM> Install-Package System.Reflection.TypeExtensions
```

now you can get the methods as follows:

```
GetProperties - typeof(Something).GetProperties();
```

GetCustomAttribute - CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(Args may vary)